# Suggested edit not returned by API

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, editing

This suggested edit: https://dba.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/20375 is not returned by the /suggested-edits/{ids} API call:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/suggested-edits/20375?site=dba returns

> {"items":[],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":297}

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug in the API? Other suggested edits like [this one](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/suggested-edits/20374?site=dba) do work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because [the referenced post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123089/how-to-name-table-variable-function-unique-constraint/123122#123122) has been deleted.

The API excludes (most) deleted data (usually).

Comment: Although, it would be nice if the API mirrored the web pages, where we *can* see the suggested edit anyway.